# Clear app cache every 20 seconds

Tags: jquery, cordova, caching, phonegap-build

I am developing application using JQuery mobile in phonegap; I'm a phonegap newbie.  The app has multiple html pages.  The cache is stored via an Ajax call.  How can I clear the entire application cache every 20 minutes without logging out my customer?  The customer's id is in the app's local storage and also must be retained.

Comment: Improved grammar and wording.

Comment: Check this plugin: https://github.com/moderna/cordova-plugin-cache